# No matching function for call in template struct

Tags: c++

there. I am new to C++ and trying to practice something with graph algorithm. I defined two structs in a class:

---

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

enum GraphType{undigraph, digraph, undinetwork, dinetwrok};

template <class T>
struct EdgeType
{
    T head, tail;
    int cost;
    EdgeType(T head, T tail, int cost)
    {
        this->head = head;
        this->tail = tail;
        this->cost = cost;
    }
};

template <class T>
struct Edge
{
    T adjvex;
    int lowcost;
};

template <class T>
class MGraph
{
private:
    int vexnum, edgenum;
    GraphType kind;
    vector<vector<int> >edges;  //二维邻接矩阵
    vector<T> vexs; //顶点表

public:
    ...
    void Prim(int v);       //Prim算法求最小生成树
    void Kruskal(vector<EdgeType<T> > &tree);   //Kruskal算法构造最小生成树
    int getMiniNum(Edge<T>* edges);
    void getGraph(vector<EdgeType<T> > &graph);

};
```

---

and here are errors in my CPP file:

---

```
template <class T>
void MGraph<T>::Kruskal(vector<EdgeType<T> > &tree)
{
    int i;
    vector<EdgeType<T> > graph;
    getGraph(graph);
    tree.resize(vexnum-1);
    ...
}
template<class T>
void MGraph<T>::getGraph(vector<EdgeType<T> > &graph)
{
    graph.resize(edgenum);
    int min = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < vexnum; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if(edges[j][i] < INFINITY && i != j)
            {
                char s1 = graph[k].head = getVexValue(j);
                char s2 = graph[k].tail = getVexValue(i);
                int p = graph[k].cost = edges[j][i];
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    EdgeType<T> e;
    for(i = 1; i < edgenum; i++)
    {
        for(j = edgenum-1; j >= i; j--)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        {
            if(graph[j].cost < graph[j-1].cost)
            {
                e = graph[j-1];
                graph[j-1] = graph[j];
                graph[j] = e;
                e = graph[j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C "C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j4 SHELL=cmd.exe -e -f  Makefile"
"----------Building project:[ test - Debug ]----------"
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'D:/test/test/test'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/g++.exe  -c  "D:/test/test/test/main.cpp" -g -O0 -Wall  -o ./Debug/main.cpp.o -I. -I.

D:/test/test/test/MGraph.cpp: In instantiation of 'void MGraph<T>::Kruskal(std::vector<EdgeType<T> >&) [with T = char]':
D:/test/test/test/main.cpp:57:17:   required from here
D:/test/test/test/MGraph.cpp:368:2: error: no matching function for call to 'EdgeType<char>::EdgeType()'
tree.resize(vexnum-1);
^
D:/test/test/test/MGraph.cpp: In instantiation of 'void MGraph<T>::getGraph(std::vector<EdgeType<T> >&) [with T = char]':
D:/test/test/test/MGraph.cpp:367:16:   required from 'void MGraph<T>::Kruskal(std::vector<EdgeType<T> >&) [with T = char]'
D:/test/test/test/main.cpp:57:17:   required from here
D:/test/test/test/MGraph.cpp:415:2: error: no matching function for call to 'EdgeType<char>::EdgeType()'
graph.resize(edgenum);
^

D:/test/test/test/MGraph.cpp:432:14: error: no matching function for call to 'EdgeType<char>::EdgeType()'
EdgeType<T> e;
^

mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [Debug/main.cpp.o] Error 1
test.mk:93: recipe for target 'Debug/main.cpp.o' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/test/test/test'
mingw32-make.exe: *** [All] Error 2
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'All' failed
7 errors, 29 warnings
```

---

I don't know how to fix this, would anyone please help me out here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You do know that [templates really can only be implemented in header files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)?

Comment: `EdgeType` has no default constructor, so either add one or pass arguments to `EdgeType<T> e;`